# No "and" between author names in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran, paper

I use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` for a paper and bibtex with entries like the following:

```
@InProceedings{
author = {Author1, A. and Author2, B. and Author3, C.}
title = {blabla}
..
}
```

In the references/bibliography this is displayed as `A. Author1, B. Author2, **and** C. Author3`. I recently saw another paper, in which the `and` before the last author was omitted. How can I achieve this? Do I have to "hardcode" the string with commas in between?

I would also appreciate smaller spacing, e.g., between abbreviated first names and the last name.

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` as your tag suggests or not?

Comment: The delimiter between names is controlled by the style you use. You can not change it in the `.bib` file (you will always have to use `and` as separator in the `.bib` file). What style do you use?

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong tag: I'm using bibtex via TeXstudio. I use bibliographystile IEEEtran.

Comment: Just use another style. Or create your own with makebst. Or switch to BibLaTeX.

Comment: By making this change, in the BST file, **from** `FUNCTION {bbl.and}{ "and" }` **to** `FUNCTION {bbl.and}{  }`, you can omit the `and` before the last author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Locate the file `IEEEtran.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `IEEEtran-noand.bst`. (You are obviously free to choose another name.) Important: Don't edit an original, un-renamed file from the TeX distribution
- Open the file `IEEEtran-noand.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your .tex files will do fine.
- Inside the file `IEEEtran-noand.bst`, locate the following line (it should be on line 193):

  ```
  FUNCTION {bbl.and}{ "and" }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  FUNCTION {bbl.and}{ "" }
  ```
- Save the file `IEEEtran-noand.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-noand}` to `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-noand}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abcd,
 author  = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor and Carlo Cuthor and Doris Duthor",
 title   = "Thoughts",
 year    = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-noand}

\begin{document}
\cite{abcd}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```